# How to count the number of trades made on a Excel spreadsheet using a custom conditional formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, binance

## Consider the following:

You have an Excel spreadsheet that contains the `Trade History` of a particular trading account from `Binance Exchange`.

This file has stored the information in a way that you can know how a particular trade got `"FILLED"`, meaning that a trade of a specific `SIDE` should have another one of the **opposite** `SIDE`, so

- If the first trade for a particular symbol had `BUY` as the initial `SIDE` (Entry) then the last trade for that particular symbol must have `SELL` as the final `SIDE` (Exit).
- Similarly happens if the first trade had `SELL` as the initial `SIDE` (Entry) the last trade must then have `BUY` as the final `SIDE` (Exit).

However, there are some tricky stuff in this spreadsheet, here's a sample of it:

| Date(UTC) | Symbol | Side |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-27 10:39:45 | GALBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:39:44 | GALBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:39:44 | GALBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:58 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:24 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:22 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:21 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:21 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:15:00 | MATICBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:14:50 | MATICBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:14:48 | MATICBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:51:38 | APEBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:43:42 | GALBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:43:34 | GALBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:43:33 | GALBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:43:32 | GALBUSD | BUY |

As can be seen, the history of trades is sorted from the last one to the to the first one made, it can be assumed that:

- All of the trades got completely `FILLED` (For every Entry made there's an Exit made)
- Any symbol could have been traded ***again*** later on.
- The amount of trades of one side aren't necessarily equal to the amount of trades of the opposite side, for instance in the picture above, the first trade for `APEBUSD` immediately `FILLED` the order while its exit trade got distributed in 5 `SELL` orders.

How could the Excel function `COUNTIF` be adapted to estimate the total amount of trades made?

In the picture above, assuming there were no more data, the total amount of trades would be **3**

Comment: Can you further explain bullet 3? Also, what would be the explanation for the final info of 3 for total amount of trades? It could be helpful to post your data as data, not picture (https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: You can get the same answer just by counting the number of different symbols GALBUSD, APEBUSD and MATICBUSD  - can you explain why that would be incorrect plz?

Comment: How would you be able to decipher a trade that was made ***again later*** as you describe?

Comment: Sure, I already edited the post to show the actual data instead of a picture. Regarding a further explanation of the 3rd assumption: When you trade on Binance Futures, sometimes the orders you place, regardless its `SIDE` and `TYPE` (`LIMIT` or `MARKET` orders), don't get immediately filled due to a lack of liquidity at that time in the market, that's why you see several records for *LONGING*  `GALBUSD` and `MATICBUSD` but not for `APEBUSD` @P.b

Comment: Because a trade should be considered as a single entry with a single exit, in my case the entry is distributed among several small records instead of just one, the same happens with the exit for a trading pair given. @TomSharpe

Comment: So if a `Symbol` has both a `BUY` and `SELL` value related it should count as one, regardless the count of sell/buy?

Comment: If it started with `BUY` it would end with a `SELL` value, that would be 1 `LONG` trade , while in the other hand if it started with `SELL` it would end with a `BUY` value meaning that would be 1 `SHORT` trade, both cases are counted independently @P.b

Comment: So if for instance for one Symbol you'd have 4x SELL listed and 4x BUY. How would you know it's 4 trades (all individual trades), or 2 (1 BUY transaction with 3 long transaction an 1 SELL with 3 BUY transactions)

Comment: The data is well explained, but I have question about the problem you want to solve. When you state: *How could the Excel function COUNTIF be adapted to estimate the total amount of trades made?* trades made by Symbol? Each line in your example is a trade, but I don't think the problem is to count the lines. Then you state that the total amount of trades is 3. I would say you need to define another term: transaction (from BUY to SELL for a given symbol and vice versa). Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: If all trades must be filled (at least one entry and one exit point for every symbol for a range of dates), then you have as many filled trades as symbols you have. You have three symbols, then 3 filled trades. Maybe some additional sample is needed to cover other cases or more clarifications.

Comment: I see, you have a point, what I'm actually looking to know is how to count the *first* transaction from `BUY` to `SELL` for a given symbol and vice versa including repetitions in the rest of the data, do you happen to know how to do that? @DavidLeal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement:

> All of the trades got completely FILLED (For every Entry made there's an Exit made)

It would be enough to count unique pair of elements `{Symbol, Side}` by row and divide ty two. We can use `UNIQUE` for that

```
UNIQUE(B2:C22)
```

It produces the following output:

```
GALBUSD     SELL
APEBUSD     SELL
MATICBUSD   SELL
MATICBUSD   BUY
APEBUSD     BUY
GALBUSD     BUY
```

Each symbol appears in pairs `{BUY, SELL}`, no we just need to count distinct (unique) symbols from previous result. **BUT** you need to take into account that there are certain Excel functions that **don't accept an array as input argument (first argument)**, it has to be a *range*. That is the case of [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34):

[image: documentation of COUNTIF]

Therefore the following formula produces an error, because the output of `UNIQUE/FILTER` *is an array, but not a range*:

```
LET(set, FILTER(UNIQUE(B2:C22), {1,0}), COUNTIF(set, UNIQUE(set))) -> ERROR
```

We need to circumvent this by using a function that doesn't have this constraint. For example we can use `MATCH/XMATCH` to achieve the same. In cell: `E2` we have the following formula (see screenshot below):

```
=LET(set, FILTER(UNIQUE(B2:C22), {1,0}),
 subset, XMATCH(set, UNIQUE(set)), 
 SUM(FREQUENCY(subset, UNIQUE(subset)))/2)
```

We use `LET` function to avoid repeating the same element in the formula. We use the name `set` for selecting the symbols: `FILTER(UNIQUE(B2:C22), {1,0})` (only from the unique rows). The partial result is:

```
GALBUSD
APEBUSD
MATICBUSD
MATICBUSD
APEBUSD
GALBUSD
```

We use the name `subset` for the array that matches the positions of unique element, i.e.: `XMATCH(set, UNIQUE(set))`, here the partial result:

```
1
2
3
3
2
1
```

`FREQUENCY(subset, UNIQUE(subset))` calculates the frequency of such positions, the partial result is:

```
2
2
2
0
```

**Note**: The last row of previous result corresponds to the last open bins frequency generated by `FREQUENCY` function. Since we are creating the bings based on the unique values of `subset`. The last open bins (values greater than the max unique values of `subset`) will be always `0`. Check [FREQUENCY documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/frequency-function-44e3be2b-eca0-42cd-a3f7-fd9ea898fdb9) for more information.

Because we should have at least one `BUY` per `SELL` or vice versa, we just need to `SUM` the frequency and divide by two.

Here the output:

[image: sample excel file]

Comment: I may have misunderstood comment 4 by NoahVerner regarding `LONGING`. But if that would be a possible `Side` value it'll possibly give false positive result. I edited my answer to workaround that using O365, but Noah does not have access to The newer Office version.

Comment: Thanks I see, @P.b but it was not stated in the question, right? It needs to be specified in the question. The approach is totally different.

Comment: That's true. The quality of the question description is not as nice as the challenging solution, but I liked tackling the problem, even though I'm still unsure if the suggested answer is actually what was intended.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining very well your solution, I think your approach solves my problem, and also thanks for letting me know to consider improving the quality of my questions to make them match with the context provided, I will deliver that the next time. Today I know a little bit more .

Answer (score 1):

The following formula gets you the number of unique Symbols that have at least 1 SELL and 1 BUY Side:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
            SIGN(
FREQUENCY(
          IFERROR( 
                  MATCH(Table1[Symbol]&"BUY",Table1[Symbol]&Table1[Side],0)
                  *ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Symbol]&"SELL",Table1[Symbol]&Table1[Side],0)),
                  ""), 
                   
          MATCH(Table1[Symbol]&"BUY",Table1[Symbol]&Table1[Side],0)
          *ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Symbol]&"SELL",Table1[Symbol]&Table1[Side],0)))))
```

I used match to get the row number of the first matching row of the Symbol with Buy Side if it also has both a Sell Side. The IFERROR is making the error values a blank, so the FREQUENCY formula will not error.

The MATCH part is repeated and wrapped in FREQUENCY to get the count of each unique distinct number. Wrapping that in SIGN gives 1 for each unique distinct count FREQUENCY returned.
SUMPRODUCT sums the 1's, so returns the unique distinct count.

I think the SUMPRODUCT makes it unneeded to enter this with `ctrl+shift+enter` in older Excel versions. Unable to test that.

The screenshot below shows the arrays this function returns for the MATCH, FREQUENCY and SIGN.

[image]

In Office 365 the same logic can be narrowed down to the following:

```
=LET(sell, UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Symbol],Table1[Side]="SELL")),  
     buy,UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Symbol],Table1[Side]="BUY")),
SUM(--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(sell,buy))))
```

Comment: I'm sorry to type this, but I'm unable to redo your solution even though I set the same functions with the default language installed.

Comment: I created a table from the data and used table references. Change them accordingly. Also what Excel version do you have?

Comment: My Excel version is `Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (versión 2209 compilación 16.0.15629.20152) de 64 bits`. I also created converted my data to an actual table before trying your code above.

Comment: What error does it say?

Comment: `There's an issue with this formula, aren't you trying to introduce a formula? When the first character is an equal sign (=) or a negative sign (-), Excel thinks that is has to do with a formula...`

Comment: I typed the following code adapted to my spanish version of Excel: `=SUMAPRODUCTO(
            SIGNO(
FREQUENCIA(
          SI.ERROR( 
                  COINCIDIR(Tabla1[Symbol]&"BUY",Tabla1[Symbol]&Tabla1[Side],0)
                  *ESNUMERO(COINCIDIR(Tabla1[Symbol]&"SELL",Tabla1[Symbol]&Tabla1[Side],0)),
                  ""), 
                   
          COINCIDIR(Tabla1[Symbol]&"BUY",Tabla1[Symbol]&Tabla1[Side],0)
          *ESNUMERO(COINCIDIR(Tabla1[Symbol]&"SELL",Tabla1[Symbol]&Tabla1[Side],0)))))`

Comment: When I look at the cell in which I typed the code, it shows that the first `Tabla1[Symbol]` parameter is blue-marked just as the elements in the `Symbol` column, however it doesn't happen the same with the rest of the parameters, it seems like a syntax problem tho.

Comment: Does your version of Excel have `,` or `;` as a separator for formula arguments? In that case replace all `,` by `;`. Otherwise there may be a hidden character in the table headers causing it not to be picked up by the formula. You could workaround by selecting the ranges range-by-range within the formula and when selected clicking the actual table range from top (excluding header itself) to bottom. Repeat until all ranges link to actual ranges.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(FREQUENCY(IFERROR(MATCH(B2:B22 &"BUY",B2:B22&C2:C22,0)*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B22&"SELL",B2:B22&C2:C22,0)),""),MATCH(B2:B22&"BUY",B2:B22&C2:C22,0)*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B22&"SELL",B2:B22&C2:C22,0)))))` this is the non-table version