# Excel: Calculations with two variables, that both share the same ID

Tags: excel, database, dataframe, excel-formula, index-match

I have been working on a little project in which I analyze some data from a game that I play. My dataset looks like this:

[image: Data]

As you can see, it consists of:

- Match ID
- Map the match was played on
- Team name
- First pick, second pick and third pick (characters/players)
- Points the teams won from this match
- What side they played on (A or B)
- Who won
- Whether they're in the top 64 teams

Currently I am trying to analyze how certain picks perform against other picks. For example, I would like to see how the Xelor first pick (cell D2) performs against all other first picks. To do this, I would need to count the amount of times the Xelor first pick played against all other first pick, and how many times the Xelor pick won. I don't have any problems doing that, but the catch is that I need to make sure I only compare the Xelor first picks with other first picks from the same match (same match ID). For example, I would compare the Xelor first pick (D2) vs the Steamer first pick (D3), as they share the same match ID.

I came up with a messy solution earlier with simple formulas, but it made for a table that had no data every other row, which resulted in some problems analyzing the data. I am now struggling with the Index and Match functions to make a pretty table for my needs, but I am having a hard time.

If anyone could give me a hand on how to do this, or has any clever ideas on how to analyze all picks vs other picks, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in `M2` cell:

```
=IF(L2="","",COUNTIFS(TB_GAMES[W/L/D],"Win", 
 TB_GAMES[Pick 1],L2,TB_GAMES[Match],$K$2))
```

[image: sample excel file]

Then you can expand the formula down.

In `L` column you have the unique values from users given the Match (`K2`) and the **Pick 1** column values.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(TB_GAMES[Pick 1], TB_GAMES[Match]=K2))
```

### Update

In case you want to calculate the scores for all the Pick 1 players at once. You can try the following:

```
=LET(winSet, FILTER(TB_GAMES[Pick 1], TB_GAMES[W/L/D]="Win"),
  matches,XMATCH(winSet, UNIQUE(winSet)),
  freq,FREQUENCY(matches, UNIQUE(matches)), SORT(HSTACK(UNIQUE(winSet), 
  FILTER(freq, freq<>0)),2,-1)
)
```

**Note**: Because we are using a `FILTER` function we cannot use as *range* input argument for `COUNTIF` or `COUNTFS`, so we try to use `XMATCH/FREQUENCY` as a way to achieve the same result. For more information about this see my answer to the question: [How to count the number of trades made on a Excel spreadsheet using a custom conditional formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961335/how-to-count-the-number-of-trades-made-on-a-excel-spreadsheet-using-a-custom-con/73974464#73974464), we use here the same idea and the explanation would be the same.

The `HSTACK` function is used just to combine the result having the winners and the number of wins for each player. Finally the result is sorted by score.

This would be the result on `O2` cell:
[image: updated screenshot]

Comment: Hey David,

Thanks a lot for your answer! I just played around with it and I don't think I understand it entirely. How does your answer differ from me just copying and pasting the match, pick 1 and W/L/D columns?

To clarify, I am trying to find how many times a 'Xelor' faced a 'Steamer' for example, meaning they have to be part of the same match. On the screen you posted for example, I can see that an 'Eniripsa' faced an 'Osamodas'  twice (matchs 45711 and 45715).

Please let me know if I misunderstood anything, and thanks again for your help :)

Comment: In cell `K2` you specify the match, as per your question the comparison is only when both players are in Pick 1 and playing the same match. My formula calculates the wins for players on the same match and being in the Pick 1. The formula doesn't address multiple math. The match is an input. Considering multiple match is another problem.

Comment: @Joost I updated my answer to include all the scores. Now I see you provided an answer, where you are looking for something similar, but not the same, I hope this update helps on your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that both the Unique function and the Xlookup functions made this an easy problem to solve.

First, I made a new column showing just the unique match ID values:

```
=UNIQUE(A:A)
```

Then, next to that column I looked up the first pick of the A side team using Xlookup:

```
=XLOOKUP(M2;A:A;C:C;;0;1)
```

I then did the same in another column for the team on the other side using an inverse search direction:

```
=XLOOKUP(M2;A:A;C:C;;0;-1)
```

Lastly, to see which of the two first picks won, I used this formula in a fourth column:

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(M2;A:A;H:H;;0;1)="Win";N2;O2)
```

This resulted in the following table (M:P):

[image: new table]

Thanks for the help, David!