# How to search for the most common sequence of 6 letters in Excel file?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of 50k+ URL's, and am looking for the most common 3/4/5/6 letters in these URLs (barring .com/.org/etc).

So if the URLs are `strings.com` and `string2.com`, it would tell me that `string` is the most common sequence of letters.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried `=INDEX(range, MODE(MATCH(range, range, 0 )))`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is it a requirement that letters are adjacent?

Comment: @MichaelL would you share a sample input data of your URL, so we can have something to test based on some of your input values? Please provide the information using table markdown format. You can use [Table Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)

Comment: @MichaelL I responded to your question, generating some sample data, for the problem I think you want to solve, please review it and let me know if that is what you are looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would like to find the most frequent sub-strings for a set of different sizes (6/5/4/3). Let's say your data is in column `A`. You would like to know the most common substrings for all possible sizes in the list.

In cell `C1` we generate the expected sizes:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,4,6,-1)
```

If you want in reverse the order, then: `SEQUENCE(1,4,3,1)`

Now for each length, we are going to find the most frequent pattern within that length from column `A`.

In cell `C2`, we are going to use the following formula (*Formula 1*):

```
=LET(maxLength, C1, strings, $A$2:$A$13, substr, LEFT(strings, maxLength),
  match, XMATCH(substr, UNIQUE(substr)),
  matchUX, UNIQUE(match), freq, DROP(FREQUENCY(match, matchUX), -1),
  maxFreq, MAX(freq), matchIdx, FILTER(matchUX, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(freq, maxFreq))),
  UNIQUE(FILTER(substr, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(match, matchIdx))))
)
```

and then **expand it to the right**, to consider different lengths on every column.

The previous formula uses `XMATCH/FREQUENCY` pattern, explained here:
[How to count the number of trades made on a Excel spreadsheet using a custom conditional formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961335/how-to-count-the-number-of-trades-made-on-a-excel-spreadsheet-using-a-custom-con/73974464#73974464) in the answer provided by @DavidLeal.

Following the idea from the answer to the question: [Find the day which had the most time spent in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74553316/find-the-day-which-had-the-most-time-spent-in-excel/74555345#74555345) provided by @DavidLeal, you can use the same idea in case you don't have `DROP` function available in your excel version (*Formula 2*).

```
=LET(maxLength, C1, strings, $A$2:$A$13, substr, LEFT(strings, maxLength),
  match, XMATCH(substr, UNIQUE(substr)), matchUX, UNIQUE(match), 
  matrix, IF(TOROW(match)=matchUx, 1,0), ones, SEQUENCE(ROWS(match),,1,0), 
  freq, MMULT(matrix, ones), maxFreq, MAX(freq),
  matchIdx, FILTER(matchUX, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(freq, maxFreq))),
  UNIQUE(FILTER(substr, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(match, matchIdx))))
)
```

Another alternative in case you cannot use `DROP` used in *Formula 1* is replacing the following line:

```
freq, DROP(FREQUENCY(match, matchUX), -1)
```

with

```
    freqRes, FREQUENCY(match, matchUX), freq, FILTER(freqRes, freqRes<>0)
```

`DROP` function is used to remove the last row of `freq` in *Formula 1* that has the value `0`. It refers to the frequency of the last open bins generated by `FREQUENCY`, so we use `FILTER` to remove such value.

If you want to have the result **without expanding to the right**, you can use the following and get the entire result in just one formula, via one of the following alternatives:

**Alternative 1**: Using `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK` as follow:

```
=LET(maxLengths, C1:F1, strings, A2:A13,
 DROP(REDUCE(0, maxLengths, LAMBDA(acc,length, HSTACK(acc, LET(
  substr, LEFT(strings, length), match, XMATCH(substr, UNIQUE(substr)),
  matchUX, UNIQUE(match), freq, DROP(FREQUENCY(match, matchUX), -1),
  maxFreq, MAX(freq), matchIdx, FILTER(matchUX, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(freq, maxFreq))),
  UNIQUE(FILTER(substr, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(match, matchIdx))))
  )))),,1)
)
```

**Alternative 2**: Using `TEXTSPLIT/TEXTJOIN`:

```
=LET(maxLengths, C1:F1, strings, A2:A13,
  bc, BYCOL(maxLengths, LAMBDA(length, LET(
    substr, LEFT(strings, length), match, XMATCH(substr, UNIQUE(substr)),
    matchUX, UNIQUE(match), freq, DROP(FREQUENCY(match, matchUX), -1),
    maxFreq, MAX(freq), matchIdx, FILTER(matchUX, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(freq, maxFreq))),
    TEXTJOIN(";",,UNIQUE(FILTER(substr, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(match, matchIdx)))))
  ))), TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",, bc), ";", ","))
)
```

**Note**: In both alternatives there is no need to use `$`-notation.

Here is the expected output using *Formula 1*:

[image: sample output file]

You can have more than one sub-string with the highest frequency, so it can return an array instead of a single value. In the previous example, the output is just a single value, but the formula assumes more than one sub-string can have the maximum frequency.

### Explanation

(based in *Formula 1*)

On each iteration (each column), we select from the name `strings` the corresponding substring (based on the maximum length). We use for that `LEFT` function.

Because `substr` name is an array (not a range, we cannot use any function from the `COUNTIF*` family). Instead, we are going to use `XMATCH/FREQUENCY` because both accept arrays.

The name `match`:

```
XMATCH(substr, UNIQUE(substr))
```

Helps to find the counts, via: `XMATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array)` every time the `lookup_array` value is found in `lookup_value`, it puts the same index position.

Now with the unique number of matches (`matchUX`), we can do the count via `FREQUENCY`. We don't need the last open bins (check the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/frequency-function-44e3be2b-eca0-42cd-a3f7-fd9ea898fdb9) of this function), so we drop the last row via `DROP` function.

Now we have the frequency (`freq`), and we need to find the maximum frequency. The `FREQUENCY` function returns the frequency for each bin (`matchUX`). So we are interested in all values from `matchUX` that has the maximum frequency (`maxFreq`). We use `FILTER` function for that. We can have more than one filtered result, i.e. the scenario where two sub-strings have the maximum frequency. Here is how we calculate the name `matchIdx`:

```
FILTER(matchUX, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(freq, maxFreq)))
```

Then the name `matchIdx`, has all the indexes from `match` name, corresponding to the maximum frequency. What we need now is to find the corresponding `substr` values. The names `match` and `substr` have the same size, so we can use `FILTER` again to find such `substr` values via `matchIdx`
using `XMATCH` function:

```
FILTER(substr, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(match, matchIdx)))
```

Finally, we use `UNIQUE` in case the maximum frequency was reached by the same substring, so we are interested only in unique substrings.

Comment: That is very extensive! Kudos for your thoroughness

Comment: Thanks @JvdV coming from you I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's just so nice to see how versatile these lambda helpers are!

Comment: I tried doing it all 3 ways you suggested, but the first one gives me a #CALC! error and the other two gives me a #NAME? error, same with JvdV's solution above.

I know I'm being stupid, but could I be missing? I have Excel 2021 on MacOS. This is my screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/xYnp8bh/excelcalc.png

Sorry for the hassle and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @MichaelL Probably because of the `DROP` [availability](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34). You should need to specify any excel version constraints via excel tag. Try the following: `=LET(maxLength, C1, strings, $A$2:$A$13, substr, LEFT(strings, maxLength), match, XMATCH(substr, UNIQUE(substr)), matchUX, UNIQUE(match), freqRes, FREQUENCY(match, matchUX), freq, FILTER(freqRes, freqRes<>0), maxFreq, MAX(freq), matchIdx, FILTER(matchUX, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(freq, maxFreq))), UNIQUE(FILTER(substr, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(match, matchIdx)))) )`

Comment: `DROP` is used after `FREQUENCY` to remove the last bins (open range), since the value of the frequency will be for this case `0`, then you can remove it using `FILTER` instead. Please let me know if that solves it, to update the answer to provide an alternative. This will fix the first formula and **Alternative 2**.

Comment: Gotcha! The solution you provided works! I was wondering if it's possible to see the 2nd/3rd/etc most frequent phrases for a substring of 8, for example. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it worked. For substring of 8. Just enter the value in `C1` cell. For the three more frequent I guess it would work from the top of my head changing `MAX(freq)` with `LARGE(freq, {1;2;3})`, try to play with that.

Answer (score 3):

The following will spill all possible consecutive 3-6 character substrings and their count in order of their respective count:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(4,,3),LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,LET(c,REDUCE(0,A1:A3,LAMBDA(d,e,VSTACK(d,LET(f,MID(e,SEQUENCE(LEN(e)-b+1),b),f)))),c)))),1),2),y,UNIQUE(x),UNIQUE(SORT(HSTACK(y,MAP(y,LAMBDA(z,SUM(--(x=z))))),2,-1)))
```

Comment: You did it again. Incredible. It won't work on a large database probably, but I love the solution.

Comment: Thanks @p.b what I tried and found here is that we can best Reduce in itself where usually we get errors when nesting lambda helpers.