# Find the day which had the most time spent in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which looks like this,

```
Sunday,      Monday,      Tuesday,     Wednesday,   Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, ...
13-Nov-2022, 14-Nov-2022, 15-Nov-2022, 16-Nov-2022, 17-Nov-2022, ...
1:00,        2:05,        0:30,        2:00,        1:00,     0:05,   0:10,     1:20, 0:14
```

I want to find the day which has the maximum sum, that is here, Sunday has 2:20
so I want a column where I mention Sunday.
Currently, I have done something like this,

```
MAX(SUMIFS(range_of_time_spent, range_of_days, a_particular_day), 
    SUMIFS(range_of_time_spent, range_of_days, a_particular_day),
    ...) # seven SUMIFS inside MAX for 7 different days
```

but this gives me 2:20, not the day

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® 2016 MSO (Version 2210)

Comment: @apostofes is your input data one row with all the information delimited by comma or three rows on each column?

Comment: three rows on each column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=TEXT(INDEX({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},MATCH(MAX(SUMIFS(range_of_time_spent,range_of_days,TEXT({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},"dddd"))),SUMIFS(range_of_time_spent,range_of_days,TEXT({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},"dddd")),0)),"dddd")
```

[image]

With older versions this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach that uses `MMULT`. In cell `A6` put the following formula:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(7,1), "dddd"),
  MATCH(MAX(MMULT(IF(A1:O1=TEXT(SEQUENCE(7,1), "dddd"), A3:O3,0),
    TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:O1)^0))),
    MMULT(IF(A1:O1=TEXT(SEQUENCE(7,1), "dddd"), A3:O3,0),
      TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:O1)^0)),0))
```

**Notes**:

- `MMULT` requires as input arguments arrays, it means you can use either ranges or arrays, so it gives *more flexibility* in case you are forced to use arrays. Let's say instead of calculating the totals of `A3:O3`, you need to perform an operation first in the range, for example: `LOG10(A3:O3)` (now it is not a range but an array) or any other operation. In this case you cannot use any of the [RACON excel functions](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions), because **they work only with ranges**.
- I borrow the idea from @ScottCraner's answer to generate the week days via `TEXT` function. Great trick `1` represents the day: `1/1/1900` that was a Sunday and so on until: `7`, i.e. `1/7/1900` that was a Saturday.

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel output]

Since you requested a solution for an older version, the above formula is more verbose. Let's use `LET` function ([Excel 2021 version](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates-365-new-functions.htm)) to avoid repetition of the same calculation defining names. It also facilitates the comprehension of the formula (You can use named ranges for some of the range too)

```
=LET(wkdays, TEXT(SEQUENCE(7,1), "dddd"), days, A1:O1, times, A3:O3,
 matrix, IF(days=wkdays, times,0), ones, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(days)^0),
 totals, MMULT(matrix, ones),INDEX(wkdays, XMATCH(MAX(totals), totals))
)
```

The main idea is to generate the `matrix` so we can perform the calculation in the way we want it. Let's try to understand the following expression first:

```
IF(a = b, c, 0)
```

If `a` is an `1xm` array and `b` an `nx1` and `c` has the same shape as `a`.  It returns an `nxm` array, where on each row is compared the corresponding element of `b` against the entire array `a`.  if there is a match it returns the corresponding value of `c`, otherwise returns `0`. Here is the mathematical representation for the elements of the resulting matrix:

[image: mathematical representation]

For example:

```
IF({1,2,3,1,2,3}={1;2;3},{10,20,30,40,50,60},0)
```

returns

```
10  0   0   10  0   0
0   20  0   0   20  0
0   0   30  0   0   30
```

If we do a matrix multiplication of the previous result: `MMULT(matrix, {1;1;1;1;1;1})` we obtain the totals per row and this is exactly what we want.

Understanding the previous logic. We just need to build the same logic adapted to our specific data:

- `wkdays` has the weekdays in a *row* array (array `b` from previous example)
- `days` the list of days (only weekday portion) in a *column* array (array `a`)
- `ones` is the unit *row* array with the same number of rows as columns has `days`.
- `times` The times, the information we want to calculate the totals (array `c`)
- `matrix` generates a matrix using the logic explained before, but applied to our case: `IF(days=wkdays, times,0)`
- `totals` is the matrix multiplication: `MMULT(matrix, ones)` returns the total of `times` per `wkdays`.

The rest is just to find the index position of the maximum of `totals` via `MATCH/XMATCH` and finally use `INDEX` to find the corresponding weekday.