# Need Excel formula to determine the most common 3 digits in position 3-5 of a numeric string?

Tags: excel, countif, sumifs

I have a column of numeric data and need to determine the most common three digits that appear in positions 3-5 in any order. For example:

```
99123456
98321889
99456777
98231666
99221457
98997000
```

Most common would be 2 1 3

Struggling with count (if and sum(if(mid

Answer (score 2):

My proposal of formula is for newer versions of Excel (2021 or 365):

```
    =LET(data,$B$2:$B$7, s_10,SEQUENCE(10,,0), s_9,SEQUENCE(9,,0),
         fr,FREQUENCY(--MID(data,{3,4,5},1),s_9)-s_10/100,
         MATCH(LARGE(fr,{1;2;3}),fr,0)-1)
```

Here `data` represents the range of data, `{3,4,5}` - positions of digits taken into account,  `{1;2;3}` - list of ranks.
For a given numbers the most frequent digits are `2`, `1`, and `3`.
If the digits occur as often, the smaller digits will be displayed first.

Comment: I am curious why you need `-s_10/100` if you remove it, you get the same result

Comment: This is needed when the digits occur equally frequently to distinguish them. Try displaying the digits {4;5;6} instead of {1;2;3}.

Comment: I see, anyway in the case of more than one digit with the same frequency, there is no unique solution. For `{4;5;6}` with frequency `3` you have `1,2`, but with frequency `2` we have `6` (provided by your solution), but it could be also: `3,4,7`. Interestingly, it provides at least one feasible solution.

Comment: There is always one solution, because there is one set of digits, but with the same frequency you have to decide in what order these digits will be given. The digit `2` (position 1) has the highest frequency (5), followed by the digit `1` which has a frequency of 4 (position 2), followed by `3` (frequency 3) position 3, the digit `9` (frequency 2) position 4. Next are four digits `4,5,6,7` (frequency 1), which according to my formula will be displayed in ascending order. Without this extra fragment, the formula would return the digit `4` 4 times, and `5,6 and 7` would get lost.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming there is no **Excel Constraints** as per the tags posted, then using the following formula this can be accomplished as well using the incredible `MMULT()` function.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α,TOCOL(MID(A1:A6,{3,4,5},1)+1),
     TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(α,MMULT(N(α=TOROW(α)),α^0))),2,-1),3,1)-1)
```

---

- Extract digits at positions `3`,`4`,`5` using `MID()` and convert the same into a single column array using `TOCOL()` this defines the variable `α`.
- Comparing each `α` with its equivalent horizontal array i.e. `TOROW(α)`.
- Using `N()` function converting each `TRUE` & `FALSE`s returned by the comparison to `1` & `0`s so as it can be used to perform a `Matrix Multiplication` of both the arrays using `MMULT()` to return SUM of the values.
- Using `HSTACK()` to horizontally stack both the arrays `α` & the one returned using `MMULT()` matrix.
- Wrapped within `UNIQUE()` function to exclude duplicates and `SORT()` the array by the `2nd` index in descending order (`-1`).
- Lastly, using `TAKE()` to get the first `3` sorted ones.

---

Comment: Your formula 'wastes resources' already at 2443 rows on my machine. To prevent this, you should do something like `u,UNIIQUE(α)` and continue with `... TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(u,MMULT(N(u=TOROW(α))...`. Then a `#NUM!` error occurs at `349526` rows on my machine. Test it on your computer and let me know.

Comment: @VBasic2008 sir are you sure about OP has got the amount of datasets. Also it wont work beyond `349525` because it reaches the max limit of the number rows is present in Excel i.e. `349526*3` --> `1048578` and not just using `UNIQUE()` it wont work still. I will try to find a way.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you can build a matrix e.g. `10*10000` instead of `10000x10000` retrieving 10 results instead of 10000. The former has to be more efficient. What do you think is the reason behind the `#NUM!` error? Is it `TOCOL`? I mean, it shouldn't be `MMULT` since `TOROW` doesn't 'complain' although there are just 16384 columns. Also, doesn't the 2443 issue happen on your end?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, I agree with you, and it help me to realise the fact that we cannot randomly use `TOCOL()` or `TOROW()` everytime even with `REDUCE()` or `MMULT()` as in this case it exceeds the limit of number of rows in excel. I have not thought about that, but you gave me a new pointer to think about a better option. However I see the only way for now is using `FREQUENCY()` function as is shown above

Answer (score 0):

This is another try, in cell `C1` put the following formula:

```
=LET(A,A1:A6, nums,TOCOL(MID(A,SEQUENCE(,3,3),1)), uxNums,UNIQUE(nums),
 freq,MMULT(N(uxNums=TOROW(nums)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(nums),,,0)),
 TAKE(SORTBY(uxNums,freq,-1),3))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The formula `MID(A,SEQUENCE(,3,3),1)` (or just `MID(A,{3,4,5},1)`) splits the digits among columns for each row for 3-5 digit positions. The name `nums` represents a column array with all selected digits and `uxNums` the corresponding unique digits. The name `freq` counts the frequency for each unique digit. We want to sort them by the frequency (`freq`) so we can use `SORTBY` for that in descending order and finally take the first three rows via `TAKE` function.

**Note**: Instead of using `MMULT` to calculate `freq`, you can use: `BYROW(N(uxNums=TOROW(nums)),LAMBDA(r,SUM(N(r=1))))`

In situations like that, where you have an array (`nums`) and you want to count values. You cannot use any of the [RACON functions](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) since all of them expect a range as input. There is a trick for that combining `XMATCH` with `FREQUENCY` that we can use:

```
=LET(A,A1:A6, nums,TOCOL(MID(A,SEQUENCE(,3,3),1)), uxNums,UNIQUE(nums),
 idx,XMATCH(nums,uxNums), freq,DROP(FREQUENCY(idx,UNIQUE(idx)),-1),
 TAKE(SORTBY(uxNums,freq,-1),3))
```

For more details, you can check my answer to this question: [How to search for the most common sequence of 6 letters in Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437303/how-to-search-for-the-most-common-sequence-of-6-letters-in-excel-file). `DROP` is used to remove the last open bins, it is not necessary in this case, I just keep it for a general case.

From a performance perspective, the `MMULT` approach is about `50%` faster than `BYROW` and `XMATCH/FREQUENCY` solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "A"-part ... I will delete my comment.

Comment: @Ike yes, I was checking and it was working, but then I realized that you are not considering that in `A`, I already selected the desired digits. Thanks anyway for your observation, maybe it can be simplified and have only one `MID`.

Comment: Updated the solution removing the extra `MID`, credit to @Ike

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses; all good suggestions. Any thoughts as to why "0" is not a valid digit?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @charliem, please if you consider my answer valuable, upvote it. What do you mean by `0` is not a valid digit? in your sample you have zeros.

Comment: Yes, the 3-digits represent sub-assemblies and 0-9 are all valid