# Find matching condition from two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This should be an easy enough question. What I want to do is match each instance where behaviour is the same value (i.e blank with blank etc) and other browser with other browser where the status is START and then STOP. Ideally, it would find these values and subtract the unit of time from each stop to each start getting the total time for that activity. The catch is that they are not sequential (see highlighted yellow) so each value must be "paired" with a corresponding STOP activity.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to check that the behavior column values you want to check they should come in pairs START-STOP, correct?, but there is no way to identify one Blank with other specific Blank, i.e. there is no an identifier to find the specific Blank, correct? It sounds to me similar to this question [How to count the number of trades made on a Excel spreadsheet using a custom conditional formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961335/how-to-count-the-number-of-trades-made-on-a-excel-spreadsheet-using-a-custom-con). Please check it in case it helps

Comment: Yes thats correct. There is no way to distinguish one blank form another so I need to match every instance of a blank STOP with a blank START if that makes sense. I don't think the solution form that post is quite suited to my needs

Comment: It would be helpful with an example of an expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way to uniquely identify each row, the option to test is checking for unique **Behavior** column value we have an even number of **Status** column value. In cell `I2`, you can use the following formula:

```
=LET(behavior, F2:F35, ux, UNIQUE(behavior), counts, COUNTIF(behavior, ux), 
  status, G2:G35,  
  diffCnts, COUNTIF(status, "START") - COUNTIF(status, "STOP"),
  blk, VSTACK({"Unique Behavior", "Status Count", "Check", "START-STOP paired?"},
    HSTACK(ux, counts, ISEVEN(counts), IF(diffCnts=0, TRUE, FALSE))),
  IFERROR(blk, "")  
)
```

and here is the output.

[image: sample excel file]

I added in the last column a check for having the same number of `START/STOP` values.

Comment: Ideally the Test column would be populated with the result of subtracting the behaviours that are pairs from each other

Comment: But there is no way to identify the pair of each one. That was my understanding from the question and comments. That is why I use a summary table instead.